# Migrating from Axis2 to CXF without changing the client code

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-axis

I am publishing a web service which is consumed by few external clients. Is it possible to migrate the web service publishing API from Axis2 to CXF without notifying my clients? Do they have to change their side of client code?
What are the other implications of this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the WSDL of the service remains the same, the client code shouldn't need to change at all.   The on-the-wire soap messages, as long as they match the wsdl, should be exactly the same.